# JAX-WS service and client versioning

Tags: version-control, jax-ws, ibm-rad

My group is getting into web services for the first time.  What is the usual way to control versioning issues with web services and clients?  We're generating our services and clients using in IBM's RAD using the wizards it presents.  The services and clients work well enough, but we're wondering how managing these will become a task going forward.

-If a service changes, and it's interface doesn't change I presume older clients would never know the difference and would work fine.

-If a service changes to add a new property to a parameter, would older clients work with it if they didn't need to set that value?

-How do people handle version control of web services as they grow in number and the number of apps using their clients grows?  What is best practice on this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of versioning that we use. One that is visible to clients (public) and one that isn't (private). This comes from (what you already touched upon) whether clients are affected or not.

If clients are affect by, for example change in XSD Schema definitions or functionality of the WS changes in such way that clients must also modify their end, we change the public version. We increment the version number in WS context root, which means that it will have different URL than the previous version. Also make sure that the code archive, in our case they are war, have also the public version, as not to overwrite the previous deployment.

For example our WS called foo is in public version 2. Its URL is `http://ourserver:8000/foo_2` and war file is called foo_2. We modified our XSD Schema, so the clients must react to the change. We update the version and now URL is `http://ourserver:8000/foo_3` and war file is called foo_3. The previous version still exists, while clients can slowly transition to the new version.

If the change does not force any action from clients, then we call this private versioning. This usually shows up, in combination with public version, as a part of a project name. Using previous example, we have a WS foo, with private version 5 and public 2. Our project for this service is called WS_foo_2_5. We now change the order in which we store incoming data. This does not effect the clients, so we change the private version. In effect we have project WS_foo_2_6. We create a code archive from it called foo_2 and deploy it with URL set to `http://ourserver:8000/foo_2`. This way we modified the version, without changing anything from clients POV.